# Are valuation rings coherent?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Serre wrote in his letter to Grothendieck(Oct. 25,1959) that valuation rings are [coherent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring).
How do you prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The valuation takes values in a totally ordered group. So any finitely generated ideal is principal (take one of the generators with the smallest valuation), hence finitely presented.

Comment: A principal ideal in a domain is free of rank 1, so finitely generated.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten that finitely generated free(or more generally projective) modules are finitely presented.

Comment: For readers who may not know the following fact.
Let $L_1, L_2$ be finitely generareted free modules over a ring.
Let $f\colon L_1 \rightarrow L_2$ be an epimorphism.
Since $L_2$ is free, the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow Ker(f) \rightarrow L_1 \rightarrow L_2 \rightarrow 0$ splits.
Hence $Ker(f)$ is finitely generated.